# Trigger a Github action on wiki edit?

Tags: github, github-actions, gollum-wiki

Our local hackerspace has a Github Wiki where we document our organisation. Some assets could be autogenerated by github actions, but in order to get there we need something to trigger the action. Is there a way to make Github Action run each time a wiki is edited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub actions can be triggered on creation or update of a Wiki page using the `gollum` event. You can add the below in your GitHub workflow yaml file for the same:

```
on:
  gollum
```

More on that in the GitHub Actions documentation for [Gollum event](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#gollum)

Comment: BTW, they named it "gollum", not to make a statement about documentation writers – afaik ;-) – but because wikis are "precious" and because this is the name of the [Ruby library](https://github.com/gollum/gollum) that GitHub wikis are based on. [Ref](https://dev.to/kalkwst/workflow-triggering-events-and-event-actions-5cec#the-gollum-event)